# Run same search on different search engine in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

My default search engine is Google. I ran a search on Google using chrome's address/search bar. Now I want to run the same search on stackoverflow.com or yahoo.com.

How can I do this with not more than couple of click/keystrokes in Chrome? Just two clicks are required to do this in IE.

Comment: A caveat of simplification - combining address and search bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No good solution till date.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo used as an example.

**The slow copy-paste way:**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L+A+X</kbd> Yahoo.com (type till tab-complete appears) Keywords <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

**The fast short keywords way:**

Right click on the address bar and click `Edit search engines...`

Enter short keywords for the search engines. (e.g. `g` for google, `b` for bing, `y` for yahoo)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>HOME</kbd> y Keywords <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

**The extension way:**

[This extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mmffncokckfccddfenhkhnllmlobdahm) embeds the options under the search and allows you to select your search term and click.

You still would have to do it manually for Stack Overflow though, it doesn't take that much effort...

There is no way to get the search term to natively stay as there is no search box in Google Chrome!

[image]

Comment: I don't want to type/paste search keywords again.

Comment: First option will search full url of the first search engine in the second search engine.

Comment: Same happens with the second option also. Its not helping me.

Comment: Check my update, a second attempt to it.

Comment: Why do you have to do it manually for stackoverflow.com? It's in the list of search engines in my version of chrome.

Comment: Because the extension doesn't support Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

> Just two clicks are required to do this in IE.

This is no longer true in IE 9 since they've done away with the search bar, making it quite similar to Chrome.

My preferred method is to use [Shortmarks](http://shortmarks.com) (a service I created) to search on multiple search engines at once.  For example, if you have a link bundle that includes Google, Stackoverflow and Yahoo, with a keyword of **!s**, you would type `!s <search phrase>` in the address bar to launch 3 new tabs with the search results of each.  But once you're at the search results page, I don't know of a generic way to retrieve the keywords without copying and pasting.